# Mysql table using LIMIT, breaks randomly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

When i run the following code it will return 100 users record from a table but when i increase the value of LIMIT from 100 to a greater number like 5000 then it will not return anything.i have total 6000 records in table. So how can i access different number of records like 2000, 3000 or even all 6000 records? kindly Guide what's wrong!

```
<?php 
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db("distributedsms",$db);
    $result = mysql_query("select * from users LIMIT 100", $db);
    $json_response = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['user no'] = $row['sno'];
        $row_array['mnc'] = $row['mnc'];
        $row_array['mcc'] = $row['mcc'];
        $row_array['lac'] = $row['lac'];
        $row_array['cell id'] = $row['cell id'];
        $row_array['lat'] = $row['lat'];
        $row_array['lng'] = $row['lng'];
        $row_array['address'] = $row['address'];//push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
        $users = $json_response;}
$fp = fopen('users_data.json', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($json_response));
fclose($fp);
echo json_encode($json_response);
?>
```

Comment: most of that loop code is pointless. why not just `while($row = ...) { $json_response[] = $row }`?

Comment: If it doesn't return anything, the chances are that the code is timing out or hitting a memory limit.... check your server logs

Comment: While you are developing turn `display_errors = On` in `php.ini`

Comment: we want both "all" as well LIMIT But LIMIT did not work after 100 users?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What happens if you limit to 101 records or 200 records?  You say it stopped working above 100 users, but you only talk about trying much higher limit values.

Comment: i also increased execution time by adding ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); at the top of code page but still didn't get results..... @Anil Singh

Comment: when i change LIMIT from 100 to any higher value then it doesn't return any result neither show a warning or error. But when i change LIMIT value below 100 it return results... @ Mike Brant

Answer (score 0):

First, enable error reporting in your INI or Script:

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
       ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will help you if there is any error/warning in case of low memory allocation or similar.

To fetch all records, you shouldn't use LIMIT, remove LIMIT from your SQL.

i.e. `select * from users`

Comment: they want to limit 5000, so they need a LIMIT

Comment: @CodeGodie - where does it say they want a limit? They're trying to apply a high limit at the moment, but want "all" as the question says: `How we get __all__ records from mysql table?`

Comment: we want both "all" as well LIMIT But LIMIT did not work after 100 users?

Comment: is this what he wants though? he mentions that he tried to raise the limit to 5000, and he did not receive anything. In that case, he wants to be able to increase the limit all the way to 5000, or even 6000 at some point. @Nixi, edit your title so that users do not get confused.

Comment: If user needs all records, why he should add limit?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `mysql_connect` as it is deprecated. Use `mysqli_connect` instead. Also, I don't think you need to iterate so much, just choose what you want in your select statement.

UPDATE: another factor on why this might be happening can also be the returned information from the database, if you have apostrophes `'` in your strings and you try to use `json_encode`, it will break, you would need to `addslashes` first.

Try the following, change your LIMIT as you wish, and let me know if you still have those errors:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT sno,mnc,mcc,lac,cell_id,lat,lng,address FROM users LIMIT 100";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $response = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        foreach($row as $k => $str){
            $row[$k] = addslashes($str);
        }
        array_push($response, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74270/discussion-on-answer-by-codegodie-mysql-table-using-limit-breaks-randomly).

Comment: Could You give me some time via Team viewer at any time if possible for you.... @CodeGodie